# Json Jbuilder v/s render :json method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

While trying to send json responses, what are the benefits that one might have using `render` method over ***jbuilder*** or vice-versa.

**For Example:**

`render :json=> @boats`

**v/s**

In index.json.jbuilder

```
json.array! @boats do |boat|   
    json.boat_name boat.name 
end
```

I tried using both the ways, but could not find any significant advantage of one over the other. The reason might be that my application is small. So i wanted to know if there was any difference between them at all in large scale applications.

Comment: From their [GitHub readme](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder): "Jbuilder gives you a simple DSL for declaring JSON structures that beats manipulating giant hash structures. This is particularly helpful when the generation process is fraught with conditionals and loops.". In your case, rendering a single resource is trivial. But if you want to render complex JSON responses blending several resources together, then using a DSL to do so makes the process more manageable.

Answer (score 3):

Jbuilder provides a DSL for generating JSON. It includes a template engine which allows you to create complex responses with helpers and conditions.

**example**

We could add this without using JBuilder by adding a `render`

```rb
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
   render json: @article 
end
```

When we reload the page now we’ll see the JSON representation of the article.

```
{"author_id":1, title:"hello", etc}
```

[image]
if you want Customizing The Response can use `as_json` like

```
   format.json { render json: @article.as_json(only: [:id, :name, :content], include: [:author, {comments: {only:[:id, :name, :content]}}]) }
```

[image: Customizing The Response can use <code>as_json</code>]

**Using JBuilder**
This works, but the code we’ve used isn’t very pretty. We could override as_json in the model but this wouldn’t be much prettier.

```
json.id @article.id
json.name @article.name
```

[image]

can use any customize  in JBuilder

Thanks for [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder?view=asciicast) can read for more information